# How to link React Native (expo) app with Nest js?

Tags: javascript, react-native, nestjs, cors-anywhere

After setting the nest js project and verifying all routes using insomnia
I've tried enabling cors

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors()
  await app.listen(3001);

}
bootstrap();
```

but I still get  [Network Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1DlT.png)

the problem seems like from the Nest js project (cors specifically)
because I tryied linking the same nest js project with react js project and everything was going fine .

Otherwise,in react native when trying something like

```
const res = await axios.get("https://www.google.com/")
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

i get all the data in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use instead of the local address `http://localhost:3001` your local IP address like: `http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3001`

Comment: I tried that but no result again sadly.
I still get the same error

Comment: Try to change `app.enableCors()`to `app.enableCors({origin: '*'} as CorsOptions)` in your NestJs boostrap function where  `CorsOptions` is import from `@nestjs/common/interfaces/external/cors-options.interface`

Comment: sorry it was my bad actually the first answer was right .
adding my local IP address was the right solution .
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this link https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors
it gives more ways to activate cors

Comment: I tried everything but nothing went well